# Ansible registered variable has attribute not found error due to multiple when conditions

Tags: variables, ansible, attributes, runtime-error

How do we check for a registered variable if only one of the two conditions turns out to be true having the same registered variable?

Below is my playbook that executes only one of the two shell modules.

```
- name: Check file
    shell: cat /tmp/front.txt
    register: myresult
  when: Layer == 'front'

- fail:
    msg: data was read from front.txt and print whatever
  when: myresult.rc != 0

- name: Check file
    shell: cat /tmp/back.txt
    register: myresult
  when: Layer == 'back'

- fail:
    msg: data was read from back.txt and print whatever
  when: myresult.rc != 0
```

Run the above playbook as

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e Layer="front"
```

I do get error that says myresult does not have an attribute rc. What is the best way to print debug one statements based on the condition met?

Note: I wish the fail to terminate the execution of the play as soon as the condition is met hence I beleive `ignore_errors` with fail will not help.

Note: The shell modules can be any Unix command.

I tried myresult is changed but that too does not help. Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at this [logical grouping of tasks: blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html)

```
- name: Check file
  block:
        - name: check file
          shell: cat /tmp/front.txt
          register: myresult
          ignore_errors: true

        - fail:
                  msg: data was read from front.txt and print whatever
          when: myresult.rc != 0
  when: Layer == 'front'
- name: Check file
  block:
        - name: check file
          shell: cat /tmp/back.txt
          register: myresult
          ignore_erros: true

        - fail:
               msg: data was read from back.txt and print whatever
          when: myresult.rc != 0
  when: Layer == 'back'
```

when the variable Layer is set to the front it will execute the shell command for front. but in case when the file doesn't exists it will give the error no such file exists and stop the play. so i have put the ignore_errors in the shell task.it will ignore it and jump to the fail module.